# Capturing custom URIs in Windows 8.1 RT's WebView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webview, windows-rt

I am porting an application from Windows 8 Phone to Windows 8.1 RT, and I have a web service that returns a custom URI that cannot be processed by Windows RT's WebView, but can be handled by Windows 8 Phone's WebBrowser.

It is handled in the Windows 8 Phone app this way:

```
private string _successUri = "app://transactions/payment/complete";

void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    var navigatedUri = e.Uri == null ? "" : e.Uri.ToString().ToLower();
    if (navigatedUri.StartsWith(_successUri))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        App.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/TransactionSuccessPage.xaml?transactionid=" + _transactionId,             UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}
```

From what I understand, Windows 8 Phone's WebBrowser control will allow attempts to navigate to unsupported URIs, considering the implementation given above.

I have attempted to use Windows RT's `WebView.NavigationFailed`, but to no avail, as the `WebViewNavigationFailedEventHandler` only returns the web service's URI (`POST`, if I'm not mistaken), and not the unsupported URI.

My research has pointed me towards `WebView.UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified`, but unfortunately it is only available for Windows 10.

Is there any other way to handle this?
Do note that I do not have access to the `WebService`, so any manipulation on that end is out of my reach.